# How to get last element of array in ejs

Tags: node.js, arraylist, ejs

Am using nodejs as backend.

i need to retrieve last element of array in ejs.

this is my code:

```
<% for(var i=0; i < user.booking.length; i++) { %>
   <%= user.booking[i].can_name %>
   <%= user.booking[i].can_quantity%>
<% } %>
```

My output:

```
Bisleri     3
Bisleri     3
Bisleri     4
Bisleri     4
Kinley      3
Bisleri     8
```

How can i get last value alone.

Comment: Hi, Did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

The following should work:

```
<%= user.booking[user.booking.length - 1].can_name %>
<%= user.booking[user.booking.length - 1].can_quantity %>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<%= user.booking[user.booking.length-1].can_name %>
<%= user.booking[user.booking.length-1].can_quantity%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should access like this as length gives you total length of an array \

```
<%= user.booking[user.booking.length - 1].can_name %>
<%= user.booking[user.booking.length - 1].can_quantity %>
```